# How can I randomize a list of integers 1 to X in CircuitPython without duplicates?

Tags: python, list, random, adafruit-circuitpython

I am creating a circuit python project and the code compiles fine but it isn't working the way I intend. This loop that I have is supposed to generate a non repeating list of integers 1 to X in a random order. It does that except 1 and 2 are always copied in there for some odd reason. Because this is in circuit python, I cannot use random.sample so thats why this is simple code but it still doesn't work.

Edit: I do need the list to end up as a list of strings instead of a list of Integers. I failed to make that clear.

```
station = 20

songs = []
loop = True
while loop == True:
    r=random.randint(1, station)
    if r not in songs:
        songs.append(str(r))
    if len(songs) == station:
        loop = False
```

Output: ['14', '3', '11', '20', '10', '17', '9', '5', '19', '17', '1', '6', '18', '1', '9', '15', '6', '11', '14', '8', '2']

In this case 2 isn't in there twice but 1 is. I just want an exact list of 1 - X randomized with no duplicates.

Comment: Create the entire list, then call `random.shuffle()` to shuffle it.

Comment: `r not in songs` will always be true, because `songs` contains strings but `r` is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting strings in the list but comparing them with ints. Convert it to a string immediately so you use consistent types.

```
while len(songs) < station:
    r = str(random.randint(1, station))
    if r not in songs:
        songs.append(r)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Comment: I never heard of CircuitPython before, didn't know it was not "regular" Python.

Comment: I understand my problem now but I still am not 100% sure how to solve it because I need the output to be a string but unfortunately its circuitpython. CircuitPython is basically a stripped down version of python created by Adafruit that you can run on the Raspberry Pi Pico with many circuitry libraries that you can run with it. I am not the greatest at programming as you can tell. I bough a compontent that was made by adafruit and I am not 100% sure how to convert to micropython as it uses an adafruit library to use this component. So I am very limited.

Comment: My code produces a list of strings. Don't you see the `str()` call on the 2nd line?

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that. It works perfectly for me now. Thank you very much. I am trying to recreate true to game fallout radio.

Answer (score 0):

Random shuffle is not hard to write, and is one of the better approaches to this problem:

```
import random

station = 20
def shuffle(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        j = random.randrange(0,len(lst))
        lst[i],lst[j] = lst[j],lst[i]

songs = list(range(1,station+1))
print(songs)
shuffle(songs)
print(songs)
```

#### Followup

OK, let's make two small modifications that improve the randomness.  In this particular case, the difference is insignificant, but in a research situation, it could be important.

```
import random

station = 20
def shuffle(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        j = random.randrange(i,len(lst))
        lst[i],lst[j] = lst[j],lst[i]

songs = list(range(1,station+1))
print(songs)
shuffle(songs)
print(songs)
```

Comment: It might not be not hard to write, but you've demonstrated that it's apparently hard to write properly :-P (since you create bias)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle?wprov=sfla1) calls this *"an example of what not to do"*.

Comment: Where do you see that?  This is what the C++ standard library std::shuffle does.

Comment: Definitely isn't.

Comment: Where I see that is that page I linked to. Let your browser search that quote. It's in the doc string of the "Naïve method".

Comment: Hmm, how did you determine that it's insignificant? With 9 items, the most likely outcome is already over 26 times more likely that the least likely outcome. The ratios appear to increase, and they have 20 items.